# exec command getting freezed

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, expect

Trying to execute remote command through TCL script.
For one of the remote machine no response is coming after command is given.

```
Not working :
expect1.7> exec ssh -x -l root asr-bng-ubuntu "/usr/local/sbin/radiusd"
root@asr-bng-ubuntu's password:   -->hangs here , but process is getting started in asr-bng-ubuntu

Same is working for diff server 
expect1.8> exec ssh -x -l root bng-sql-1 "/usr/local/sbin/radiusd"
root@bng-sql-1's password:
expect1.9>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check .bashrc or .bash_profile on remote host, there may be some errors in them, may be some long running calls.

Comment: I have exactly same bash profile for both the remote machines